# vue.js result pass to text input html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js, qr-code

I'm use vue.js and function v-for for read qr-code

**Example**

```
<ul v-for="(scan,key) in scans" :key="key" > {{scan.content}} </ul>
```

I'm must value inside {{scan.content}} example EmployeeID But I'm can't pass value to text input html.

```
<input type="text" value="{{scan.content}}">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to `<input type="text" :value="scan.content">`;
I think v-bind will work.
[v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#v-bind)

Comment: Thank you for your help.